Javascript Carousel Breaking SSRS URL String
Project:
I'm working on a screen that rotates through multiple variations of an SSRS report. I'm fairly inexperienced with JavaScript so I used a code sample from W3Schools.
Issue:
I'm feeding the string to the SSRS URL that makes the report page width. The problem is, only the first URL is changing to page width. The rest are acting like they're set to 100% when the screen changes, but the first report still remains as page width when it loops back around.
Body and JavaScript:
<body>

      <div class="ReportSec">
        <container class="Cover">
        <img src="Header_Logo_Source" alt="Logo">
        </container>
        <iframe class="mySlides" src="SSRS_Source&rc:Zoom=page%20width&rs:embed=true">
        </iframe>
        <iframe class="mySlides" src="SSRS_Source&rc:Zoom=page%20width&rs:embed=true">
        </iframe>
        <iframe class="mySlides" src="SSRS_Source&rc:Zoom=page%20width&rs:embed=true">
        </iframe>
        </div>

    <script>
        var myIndex = 0;
        carousel();
            
        function carousel() {
              var i;
              var x = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
              for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
                x[i].style.display = "none";
              }
              myIndex++;
              if (myIndex > x.length) {myIndex = 1}    
              x[myIndex-1].style.display = "block";  
            setTimeout(carousel, 10000); // Change iframe every 10 seconds
        }
    </script>    

</body>

I've tried changing the iframes to 3 of the same just to see if I was missing a bracket or something, but it is still failing to set to page width upon increment. I also tried adding a location.reload() to the increment, but that just caused the page to reload indefinitely. I believe the solution is a partial reload on increment, but I haven't worked out how to do that.
Update:
I think I tracked it down to being the style on the iframe.
.mySlides {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border: none;
}

I just can't figure out how to fix it for different size iframes.
